# Call c++ functions from Python in anaconda windows

Tags: python, c++, windows, anaconda, spyder

I've tried to call some c++ functions from Python. I am using python from windows in anaconda. 
I tried it with types, but it appears an error when loading the shared library (both .dll and .so)

DO you know any simple way to call these functions from Python?

Here you have the c++ functions:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



typedef vector<double> VE;
typedef vector<VE> VVE;

double sq_norm(VE x, VE y, double s_v, double hat_s_v) {
  double sq_norm = 0;
  int size = x.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    sq_norm += pow((hat_s_v/s_v)*x[i]-y[i],2);
  }
  return sq_norm;
}

VE gradient_rho(VE y, VVE eta, double s_v, double hat_s_v){
  int nu = eta[0].size();
  int N = eta.size();
  VE gradient(nu,0);
  for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    VVE add = VVE(nu, VE(1, 0));
    double exponential = exp(-0.5*sq_norm(eta[j], y, s_v, hat_s_v)/(pow(hat_s_v,2)));
    for (int i = 0; i < nu; ++i) {
      gradient[i] += ((hat_s_v/s_v)*eta[j][i]-y[i])*exponential/(N*(pow(hat_s_v,2)));
    }
  }
  return gradient;
}

double rho(VE y, VVE eta, double s_v, double hat_s_v){
  int nu = eta[0].size();
  int N = eta.size();
  double rho_ = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j) {
    VVE add = VVE(nu, VE(1, 0));
    double exponential = exp(-0.5*sq_norm(eta[j], y, s_v, hat_s_v)/(pow(hat_s_v,2)));
    rho_ += exponential/N;
  }
  return rho_;
}
```

The command to generate the .ddl file is:

```
cpp -fPIC -shared -o library.dll library.cc
```

The python script where I try to load the library is:

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes
import pathlib
so_file =  "C://Users//asus2//Box Sync//Box Sync//PLOM With Constraints//Code//library.dll"
c_lib = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(so_file)
```

Comment: What error do you receive when trying to load the shared library?

Comment: Also, you have extra `'` characters at the end.

Comment: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida, and also a pop up saying that the .dll file or .so file are not compatible with this operative system.

I create the .dll file with the following command:
'''cpp -fPIC -shared -o library.dll library.cc'''

where library.cc is the code posted in the question above

Comment: Translated using google `OSError: [WinError 193]% 1 is not a valid Win32 application`. It is possible that you are not providing the correct path to the .dll/.so file and python is complaining for that reason. Can you edit the question to post python code that is loading the shared library?

Comment: changes done, take a look